# I loaded my ubuntu on to a flash drive for my hp computer, but it won't open when I restart!

Tags: system-installation

I put Ubuntu on to a flash drive, then restarted and it did not come up "press f12". I changed the setting on my windows 10 settings and internal hp settings, but no luck. HELP!

Comment: See the instructions at this link (particularly the instructions and further links about UEFI), https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick , https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick#UEFI

Answer (score 1):

If you want to install Ubuntu on to your HP computer, 
use [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/) which will let you create a bootable USB. [you can also create a CD/DVD]

(Make sure you back up all your files from your PC { if your planning on only having Ubuntu on your HP computer }  and from the USB that you will use. {minimum 2GB USB is needed})

Also during installation you can partition your disk to have dual-boot for Ubuntu OS and windows OS.
Once you create the bootable USB or CD/DVD unplug the device.

Go to your BIOS system and enable boot from USB and make sure it's the first option that BIOS check for booting.

Turn off the laptop plug the bootable USB in and boot up your computer,
If you did everything correctly the BIOS will boot from USB and will bring you to Ubuntu installation screen.

then follow on screen instruction to complete the installation.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is legacy and uefi.

Windows 10 is normally setted on UEFI bios setting.

And also "normally", usb created bootable device are not allowd in secure boot (so you should change bios boot from uefi to legacy in order to see the usb bootable device, but in this way you won't be able to see windows... not a good solution).

You need to create a UEFI bootable device with ubuntu (I found [etcher](https://etcher.io/) as the best solution, download, 3 click procedure, uefi usb ready) then from windows 10 (with usb pen plugged) simply Shift+reboot and select the option to boot with another device, and you will choose the usb pen.

Done.

P.S. Uefi ubuntu has some "problem", you need some more effort for some normal operation, such as thrid party drivers. I personally decided to reinstall everything in Legacy, since I need reliability. But this is a personal choice. The good choice is UEFI bootable device.